# Unable to load libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

I am trying to use dbexpress component first time to connect to mysql

i got this error

> Failure to Connect : Unable to load
>   libmysql.dll

my delphi version : Delphi7

mysql 5.1.36 (wamp server installed on my windows).

can any one help me in this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB Express / Delphi 7 did not support MySQL 5 so you'll need a copy of the open source MySQL 5 drivers for DB Express ([Found here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html)).

You should also ensure that the **libmysql.dll** assembly is installed and can be found in your **PATH** variable. If  you need to find it again, it can be found in the MySQL5.X zip distribution in **lib\opt**

Comment: thanks for reply mate 
but didnt worked for me i got this error 
 unable to find procedure getSQLDriverMYSQL50

Comment: Hi learn, This sounds like a new problem specific to the Open-source drivers. You'll get much better answers if you begin a new question to address this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put libmysql.dll to your lib path. If this doesn't  help, than get another version of libmysql.dll file.

Comment: Note that the same goes for other libraries that libmysql may depend on (e.g. zlib or some encryption lib)

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 is shipped with mysql 3.x drivers. What you need is something for mysql 5. You can find one [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html),
Follow the instructions on how to add new dbexpress driver in the documentation